# Unexpected Result in Doctrine GroupBy

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I have the following repository:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$qb
    ->select('r')
    ->from('MyBundle:Rating', 'r')
    ->groupBy('r.year');

$result = $qb->getQuery()->execute();
return $result;
```

Doing a dump in the controller:

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
  object(My\Entity\Rating)#553 (5) {
  ["id":protected]=>
    int(2)
    ["index":protected]=>
    int(1)
    ["year":protected]=>
    int(2010)
    ["percentage":protected]=>
    float(2.5)
  }
  [1]=>
  object(My\Entity\Rating)#550 (5) {
  ["id":protected]=>
    int(1)
    ["index":protected]=>
    int(1)
    ["year":protected]=>
    int(2016)
    ["percentage":protected]=>
    float(0)
  }
}
```

1. I was expecting an array with the years as indexes, with the values being an array of objects that match the year, Should that not be the case?
2. there are about 10 records in the db. some how only these 2 show up. Only records for two different years are entered, which may be the reason there are only two records. Does anybody know why?

How do I fulfill the expectation in 1?

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine gives out objects by default. If you want to get an array with the resulting data you can use

```
$result = $qb->getQuery()->execute(null, Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

You need to include Doctrine\ORM\Query for this or you just use

```
$result = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

The reason you only get data about those two years is

```
->groupBy('r.year');
```

which eliminates duplicate entries. Without it you will get them all.

Comment: thanks for looking into it, but it is not bringing me closer yet. By removing the groupBy, the goal of this exercise will be omitted. Also, to be more correct, by default Doctrine gives out an ArrayCollection with objects.